# Call upon data from an external API into a Rails 5 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking documentation/tips on importing data from an external API.

I'm building a website where users can add a company to their profile. However, I want people to be unable to create duplicate companies.

Therefore I want to call upon data from the official government API to verify the existence of the dossier integer by matching it to the integer entered on the form.

Any suggestions/explanations/tips are welcomed. If I find the solution I will obviously share this here.

Thanks in advance,
Julian

Answer (score 3):

You can add a unique constrain to the name of the company, so you avoid duplicates

In **Company.rb** you can add the following validation:

```
validates :name, uniqueness: true
```

You also can use `find_or_create_by` like this to avoid duplicates

```
Company.find_or_create_by(first_name: 'company_name') do |company|
  company.location = 'Wherever'
end
```

Here you are saying: Find the first company named 'company_name' or create a new one with a different location.

References:

[reference for model validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness)

[reference for find_or_create_by](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by)

Comment: Thanks, a nice "quick and dirty" solution. However, this would still not refrain users from creating the same company over and over again with a different integer, or use a number that doesnt actually represent the company's official dossier. You should see it as a security measure of sorts. I'm intending on using the API to make this functionality air tight.

Comment: @JulianHoogendoorn: huh? With the uniqueness validation, users won't be able to create duplicate companies. Isn't that what you are asking? (you should, of course, back the app-level uniqueness validation with actual unique index in the database. That will make it impossible to violate).

Comment: Why not? what diferent integer? this answer is the correct one, if you consider this answer is not the correct one, please provide more context to help you. For example you can provide which fields you need to validate as unique. Or maybe you mean how to interact with this 'government api' and check his uniqueness, so we would need the documentation of this api, or the name, or something. Any info could help to clarify your idea

Comment: Every legal company within the netherlands is registered with the KVK (similar to the Chamber of Commerce). People that create these companies are going to be responsible for all the vacancies that fall under these companies. Therefore, the authenticity (and legality) of these companies must be a requirement.

Comment: @JulianHoogendoorn: in this case, this is administrative problem, not technical one. Hire a human that will sit and check uploaded registration certificates or something.

Comment: Please dont make me explain the reason why I want this specific solution. I'm simply looking for an answer to my question, not a solution for my problem.

Comment: @JulianHoogendoorn: _this_ is the answer to your question. (question being "how to prevent users from creating duplicate companies") (also ProTip for you: `@mention` the users you reply to, they'll get a notification. If you want their response, that is)

Comment: @JulianHoogendoorn: nah, it should be `@SergioTulentsev` :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Gotcha, nailed it